# Will I experience pain if I cut back to Visual Studio Express?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-express

With the upcoming release of Visual Studio 2010, and all the lovely new features in C# 4.0, I would really love to update from 2008. However, over the last few years, I've managed to get student pricing, or even free versions via the MSDN Academic Alliance.

Now I am no longer a student.

I can't seem to justify the [$AU500](http://www.citysoftware.com.au/Browse/41b958d9bcb6442d83e87508fbc99b6d001ItemDetail.aspx) pricetag of even the Standard version for what is at the moment, essentially a hobby. As much as I may like for it to be, it just isn't paying the bills.

So, I've read on the Microsoft site that there's no non-commercial clause in the Express version EULA which is good because I do the occasional bit of paid work in it. How much is missing from the Express version though, compared to Professional (what I use currently, and what the 2010 beta is)? Am I likely to go through withdrawal pains as I reach for something that just isn't there?

As far as addons go, the only one I've really played with is VisualSVN, and I can live with just using TortoiseSVN manually. Anything else I should be aware of?

Comment: You can use AnkhSVN (free add-in) for SVN access from Visual Studio. See here: http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/

Comment: Cătălin, add-ons don't work with Express Editions, which is presumably why the OP mentioned the ones he's using.

Comment: Correct, and correct. Also, my experiences with Ankh have been less than stellar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version comparisons can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcbsd3cz%28VS.80%29.aspx): (For 2008) (Edit: A far more in depth document can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=727BCFB0-B575-47AB-9FD8-4EE067BB3A37&displaylang=en#filelist))

The things that leap out to me as features *I* wouldn't want to be without are:

- Extensibility (no plugins like VisualSVN or Resharper)
- Source Code Control
- Remote debugging
- 64-bit compiler support (x64) (from the first link, though the document implies you *can* make 64bit apps...)
- SQL Server 2005 integration
- No setup projects (for making MSI installers)
- Limited refactoring
- Some missing debugging tools (especially the threads window)

If you can live without those (and the other limitations that wouldn't bother me personally) then I guess that you'll get by with Express just fine.

---

Final thought: Express isn't your only option for free .net development, there is also [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) which has some advantages (SVN integration, compact framework support) over Express. Though I'm sure it has many limitations too.

Comment: +1 for SharpDevelop - it's got minor issues, but it's free and performs almost the same as VS. What's not to love?

Comment: Question about SharpDevelop: Do you know if it will support .NET 4.0 and by extension C# 4.0 at release, or is there something in the editor itself that would prevent this?

Comment: No idea about 4.0. I keep a copy on a USB key as a just-in-case measure, but I rarely use it so I'm not really up on how long it takes them to add the cutting edge features.

Comment: Well, for the record, I did some searching. According to this blog post by the #Develop team, there's big changes needed. Whether a side-by-side release is in the future isn't discussed though. Should be interesting. http://laputa.sharpdevelop.net/CommentView,guid,39534573-5893-46b6-866c-a7743e03f68b.aspx

Comment: @Matthew:
Those 'big changes' in the build system are already done (well, mostly - some less important features such as adding/removing project configurations still aren't reimplemented).
You can find alpha versions of SharpDevelop 4.0 for .NET 4.0 Beta 1 on http://build.sharpdevelop.net/BuildArtefacts/

Answer (score 4):

Do you do any entrepreneurial work? If you're building the next killer app, check out BizSpark: http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/

Comment: Looks very interesting, but do you know what their definition of 'software-plus-services' that they keep refering to everywhere is?

Comment: Not sure if they post a definition anywhere (it's probably in their legalese somewhere), but my reading of it is the 'plus-services' component is software hosted somewhere, managed by you and providing services to your users, but the software itself isn't distributed to your users. Stack Overflow itself would fall into that category.

Comment: As someone who recently "graduated" from BizSpark. The only requirement for exiting without a fee was completing a simple enquiry. In those three years I had every Microsoft program I could wish for to start up my one-man (after hours) enterprise! After three years I had enough funds to enroll in the Action Pack for Development (a measily 600 to 350 a year) to keep getting the latest versions of their software. Strongly recommended!

Answer (score 2):

There is new program now available from Microsoft to allow web developers to access the Microsoft Stack similar to the BizSpark program.

It is called [Website Spark](http://www.microsoft.com/web/websitespark/).  VS 2008 Professional Edition and SQL Server 2008 Web Editon are some of the tools available through the program.

Answer (score 1):

Of all things I would probably miss the ability to install extensions. Especially tools like AnkhSVN and TestDriven.NET have grown invaluable to me...

I would seriously consider investing some money in purchasing VS especially if you can get some of that back by using it for jobs.

Maybe switching to Eclipse and Java is an option for you?

EDIT:
By the way, investing a few hundred dollars is common among ex-students. If you were a designer you would probably have to invest $1000 on Adobe software.

Comment: I tried Java once upon a time and almost threw my PC out the window just trying to make a simple GUI telnet style application... Though, that was many years ago now.

Comment: Also, if I could get a solid job as a developer (or as anything for that matter), then the price wouldn't be an issue. The issue is that I get one job here, then another a few weeks later, and...

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to have solutions with multiple project types (so no mixed language solutions), or solution folders either.

Comment: I only really use C#, so this isn't an issue (for me), but it's worthy noting.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing that is missing is the ability to build an installer for a solution.
The work-around is to build the installer using some open source installer for .NET, e.g. [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).

And multi-language solutions are more cumbersome (e.g. mixed C# and VB.NET).

I use the Professional version, but I didn't experience any problems with opening and building my project/solution in the Express Edition.